# gcc: how to skip compilation if no changes in source file

Tags: c++, gcc, compilation

I compile with this command:

```
g++.exe -g a.cpp -o a.exe
```

And the compiler does full a compilation even if there are no changes in a.cpp from a previous compilation.
How to skip compilation, if there are no changes in the source file?

Comment: You're going to need a build system for this.  related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52034997/how-to-make-makefile-recompile-when-a-header-file-is-changed

Comment: The compiler does what it is told to do.  You said compile; it compiled.  It is the build system that invokes the compiler that knows whether or not it needs compiling.  That might be a `makefile` and one of the many variants of `make`; it might be `cmake`; it might be part of the IDE you use; it might be one of the many alternatives to `make` that exist.

Comment: I use visual studio code with C++ extension. Seems it not has this functionality.